# How to display the largest number from a text file properly?

Tags: c++, text-files

So for my assignment I need to read a text file with student names and their test scores and display on screen the average test score and the highest test score.

The content of the text file is:

- John    Smith     99
- Sarah   Johnson   85
- Jim     Robinson  70
- Mary    Anderson  100
- Michael Jackson   92

The code I have so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void inputFile(string, string, int, int, int, int);

int main()
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int testScore = 0;
    int totalScore = 0;
    int avgScore = 0;
    int highestScore = 0;

    inputFile(firstName, lastName, testScore, totalScore, avgScore, highestScore);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void inputFile(string firstName, string lastName, int testScore, int totalScore, int avgScore, int highestScore)
{
    ifstream myFile("scores.txt");

    int i = 0;
    while (myFile >> firstName >> lastName >> testScore) {
        totalScore = totalScore + testScore;
        i++;
    }
    avgScore = totalScore / i;
    cout << "Average score: " << avgScore << endl;

    while (myFile >> firstName >> lastName >> testScore) {
        if (highestScore < testScore) {
            highestScore = testScore;
        }
    }
    cout << "Highest score: " << highestScore << endl;
}
```

When I run the program it displays the average score correctly but when it comes to the highest score it just displays "0" every time rather than displaying "100" which is the largest number in the text file. How would I make it display "100" for 'highestScore' rather than "0"?

Comment: On a note totally unrelated to your problem, *why* are you passing the variables as arguments to the `inputFile` function? Why don't you simply define them as local variables inside the `inputFile` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (myFile >> firstName >> lastName >> testScore) {
    if (highestScore < testScore) {
        highestScore = testScore;
    }
}
```

Why are you attempting to read the file again? You should have processed it at the same time as summing up:

```
while (myFile >> firstName >> lastName >> testScore) {
    totalScore = totalScore + testScore;
    if (highestScore < testScore) {
        highestScore = testScore;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Or alternatively, [rewind the file](/a/28331018/5958455) before trying to read again:

```
myfile.clear();
myfile.seekg(0);
while (myFile >> firstName >> lastName >> testScore) {
    /* stuff... */
```

Answer (score 1):

With the first loop you go through the file all the way to the end. And then it stays on the end, it will not "rewind" to the beginning automatically.

Either you have to [*seek*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) back to the beginning for the second loop (and [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the end-of-file status). *Or* calculate the highest score in the first loop too.